# How to know if user left my component route in Angular 15?

Tags: angular, angular-router

ngOnDestroy doesn't trigger when a user switches between different routes of the application.

Is there any other way to know if the user leaves my component route and destroy component then?

Comment: Have you tried router events:https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-router-events/?

Answer (score 1):

> ngOnDestroy doesn't trigger when a user switches between different routes of the application.

That's not true, `ngOnDestroy()` is called when the component is removed from DOM, see [this Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vhyj4p?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

When the route is changed (click one of the buttons), `ngOnDestroy()` is called on the component that is being removed.

You can manually destroy a component by getting the reference to it and calling `.destroy()` but that is generally not recommended.